# Vue component loses first keypress

Tags: javascript, vuejs2, vue-component

I have the following Vue component that displays a save and cancel input group addon when the input changes. Can anyone explain why the keypress is lost from the input when the textChanged value changes and how to fix it, please?

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/qk2utqdd/5/)

```
<div id="app">
  <my-input></my-input>
</div>

<template id="my-template">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label>Test</label>
    <div :class="{'input-group': textChanged}">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" ref="inp"
        @input="updateValue($event.target.value)" :value="value">
      <div v-show="textChanged" class="input-group-addon">Save</div>
      <div v-show="textChanged" class="input-group-addon" @click="cancel">Cancel</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
```

```
new Vue({
  el: '#app'
});

Vue.component('my-input', {
  template: '#my-template',
  props: ['value'],
  mounted: function() {
    this.original = this.value || "";
  },
  methods: {
    updateValue: function(value) {
      this.textChanged = this.$refs.inp.value !== this.original;
      this.$emit('input', value);
    },
    cancel: function() {
      this.$refs.inp.value = this.original;
      this.textChanged = false;
    }
  },
  data: function() {
    return {
      original: '',
      textChanged: false
    }
  },
})
```

Comment: Still testing, but it looks like the issue is in the assignment `this.textChanged = this.$refs.inp.value !== this.original;` (line 14 in the fiddle). You can change it to assign any value (`this.textChanged = 'foo'`) and it will still fail. It only gets fixed if that line or the elements that depend on that property (class and the 2 buttons) are removed.

Comment: The value is lost because the component is re-rendered and you do not store data in the component anywhere. You are binding the value of the `input` to the `value` prop. So when you force the re-render with by changing `textChanged`, Vue re-renders with the current value of `value` which is still empty. Is there a reason you are using this approach and not just binding the input using `v-model`?

Comment: @Bert Thanks, that explains what is happening, although I can't understand why its re-rendering, as I thought v-show just toggled visibility. 
I'm not using v-model on the component element as I want it to be generic and not tied to a particular model. However I now have a solution and will post for reference when complete.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So as per @Bert indicated, I need to save the value. This is the final component

```
<div id="app">
  <my-input @change="save"></my-input>
</div>

<template id="my-template">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label>Test</label>
    <div :class="{'input-group': textChanged}">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" ref="inp" v-model="current">
      <div v-show="textChanged" class="input-group-addon" @click="save">Save</div>
      <div v-show="textChanged" class="input-group-addon" @click="cancel">Cancel</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
```

```
Vue.component('my-input', {
  template: '#my-template',
  props: ['value'],
  data () {
    return {
        current: "",
        original: ""
    }
  },
  mounted: function() {
    this.current = this.original = this.value || "";
  },
  methods: {
    save: function() {
      this.$emit('change', this.current);
      this.original = this.current;
    },
    cancel: function() {
      this.current = this.original;
    }
  },
  computed: {
    textChanged: function() {
    return this.original !== this.current;
    }
  }

});

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  methods: {
    save(d) {
      //axios.post(...)
      console.log("saving: " + d)
    }
  }
});
```